# Muting an AudioStreamTrack in JS

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I am working with `getUserMedia()`, which returns a `MediaStream` containing an `AudioStreamTrack`. How can I mute the `AudioStreamTrack`? It has a `onmute` event so it should be somehow able to mute the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `track.enabled` ([https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/8j1h1j9x/) for Chrome):

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
  .then(stream => audio.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

mute.onclick = () => { audio.srcObject.getTracks()[0].enabled = !mute.checked; };
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls autoplay></audio>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="mute">mute</label>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Note that `onmute` doesn't fire in this case. It only fires if the mic is muted outside the control of JavaScript, e.g. by an end-user (although no browser implements that yet).